# How can I create a Wordpress.com site, with a blog for each user

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I Want to create a WordPress.com or a site build where an end user can create their own blog or website. How can I create a new wordpress install for each user on the front end

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean wordpress.org... not .com?

Answer (score 0):

There is [Wordpress Multisite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network), and this site has the basics laid out for you:

http://premium.wpmudev.org/manuals/wpmu-manual-2/creating-sites-using-your-sign-up-page/

Short: your signup WP form will act as a registration for a new blog in the Multisite network.